# How to create a Facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

How to create a Facebook page which has a URL as `http://www.facebook.com/mypage`. That is, the name of my page following the `http://www.facebook.com/` ?

Answer (score 3):

Your Facebook page needs to have more than 25 fans before you can secure a username (i.e. www.facebook.com/username) for the page.  More info here:

http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=900

Answer (score -1):

I can't upvote JohnnyO's answer, but he's right. The name has to be available and, once you've gotten 25 fans of the page, you can log in and request the www.facebook.com/ page.